# What is the easiest database to deploy with django on Mac OS X?

Tags: database, django

I'm writing a (hopefully) small project that would end up being distributed in binary form for Mac OS. I'm looking for a way to deploy the thing with a database that doesn't have a completely screwed up driver installation process. The mysql driver requires the mysqldb binary driver, which is a bear to compile, as is the postgresql binary driver.

I was looking into pure-python mysql drivers, and I found pymysql. Is there any way to deploy this as the driver? Can anyone suggest a way to easily distribute these things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlite will do the job just fine if it isn't too database intense. Default support in Django and the best thing: No extra dependencies needed.

Comment: At what point does sqllite buckle? When would it be advisable to deploy a more heavy duty database system?

Comment: Use it for development only, once your application is being used by multiple users at the same time or if the performance lacks due to heavy manual queries you really need something better; But by then it's probably not running on your Mac any more ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you install python using homebrew, you'll find a lot of the problems with binary drivers just go away.

Homebrew: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once you've installed homebrew, install python 2.7 using:

```
brew install python --framework
```

You'll then want to change OSX's symbolic link for the current version of Python to point to the one from homebrew. My symlink is like this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

I can't remember if I had to do anything else, basically the goal is such that when you run python from the terminal it's pointing to the one in /usr/local/Cellar.

Then you'll want to easy_install pip, again making sure it's using the right version of python.

Now you should be able to install python packages easily, even ones that use binaries. Here's the results from a fresh virtualenv:

```
(test)andrew-ingrams-imac:test andy$ pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz (70Kb): 70Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python

    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
    warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    /usr/bin/cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -O3 -march=core2 -msse4.1 -w -pipe -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    /usr/bin/cc -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/lib -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/lib build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -lpthread -o build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64

    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
    warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
Successfully installed MySQL-python
Cleaning up...
(test)andrew-ingrams-imac:test andy$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, May 19 2011, 20:48:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
>>>
```

Comment: My problem with this approach is that I would want to distribute this to non-technical people as easily as possible. I want to be able to put some binaries into a package and hand it to them.